# .htaccess file creating 500 error while creating routes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I am making a custom MVC for my project and used this .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /custommvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The file has been placed in the root folder of my project dir. Here, I am trying to prevent the access to inner directories and files and pass on the URL to my core controller:

```php
class App{

    protected $controller = 'Home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct(){
        $this->parseUrl();
    }

    public function parseUrl(){
        if(isset($_GET['url'])){
            echo $_GET['url'];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I access "localhost" on my browser the project directory does not show up, and when I specifically type in the URL for project, it shows up an internal server error (500). I think I made the mistake in `.htaccess` file but cannot find a work around. I need some help here.